# How to prevent changes in hidden inputs?

Tags: security, spring-boot, thymeleaf

**I have this input:**

```
<input type="hidden" th:field="*{procesos[__${i_pT.index}__].proceso}">
```

**What is transformed into this:**

```
<input type="hidden" id="procesos0.proceso" name="procesos[0].proceso" value="1">
```

If I change `value = "1"` and there is another `proceso` that matches it, it changes without problems. How can I prevent this?

I use it this way to keep the `proceso` data.

Comment: You can't. Don't rely on hidden fields or other HTML/JS/in-browser solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using spring you can use the following function

```
public static void copyProperties(Object source,
                 Object target,
                 String[] ignoreProperties)
```

Spring's BeanUtils.copyProperties() provides the option to ignore specific properties while copying beans
for example

```
String[] ignoreProperties = {"fieldthatisnothidden"};
BeanUtils.copyProperties(original, target, ignoreProperties);
```